# Paralell HTTP Request dynamically

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins

I need perform some requests in paralell, I saw jp@gc - Parallel HTTP Requests, but I can´t found a way to load dynamically the URL´s in to the controller;  my problem is the URLs to hit come from a JSON response; What is the way to indicate the URLs in a variable? Exist any way to manipulate the sampler using a JSR232 or beanshell to include the URLs? Or maybe how can I do a Thread Group and a HTTP sampler in execution time?

Kind Regards,

Alejandro Longas H.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a code to add URLs to the [Parallel HTTP Requests](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) sampler in the JMeter runtime:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   def testTree = ctx.getEngine().test
   def parallelSamplerSearch = new org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass<>(com.blazemeter.jmeter.http.ParallelHTTPSampler.class)
   testTree.traverse(parallelSamplerSearch)
   def parallelSampler = parallelSamplerSearch.getSearchResults().first()
   parallelSampler.addURL('http://example.com')
   parallelSampler.addURL('http://jmeter.apache.org')
   ```
4. That's it, now Parallel HTTP Request sampler should fire 2 requests to the above URLs simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Dmitri thanks, it works!, Exist a way to capture the response?

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, I´m working with your recomendations, but I see only 6 six request performed in parallell, the others is executed with a 3 sec of delay, maybe could be something of configuration? Maybe could be a limitation in de jp@gc - Parallel HTTP Requests? I was reading the documentation and I don´t found nothing relate that; maybe you know? I need perform 96 request in parallel