# Parallel HTTP Requests sampler - appending URLs in runtime

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to setup Parallel HTTP Requests sampler so that it worked with URLs I get from JSON in previous response. I've found this solution [Paralell HTTP Request dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976546/paralell-http-request-dynamically) where Dmitry T kindly provided script for appending URLs into Parallel HTTP Requests, however this script does not work for me. I can see that the list of URLs gets updated after the script execution but these URLs are not picked up by the sampler for execution.

This is the initial list or URLs

[image: preset URLs]

Script execution result

[image: JSR223 script run result]

JMeter test run result

[image: JMeter run result]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `parallelSampler.data` is getting lost somewhere somehow between these 2 samplers, I don't recall what versions of JMeter/plugins I was using by that time but I'm pretty sure that if you switch to the context of the current Sampler it should fix the problem, moreover you won't have to play with this reflection.

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Parallel HTTP Requests sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def row1 = new org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty()
   row1.addItem('https://example.com')
   def row2 = new org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty()
   row2.addItem('https://jmeter.apache.org')
   sampler.data.addItem(row1)
   sampler.data.addItem(row2)
   ```

Some form of evidence:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Dmitry, thank you so much for your prompt and useful reply. I slightly modified the script to be able to populate the URLs list dynamically
```urlsList = vars.get("URLs").tokenize(",")
for (int i = 0; i < urlsList.size(); i++)
{
 def row = new org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty()
 row.addItem(urlsList[i])
 sampler.data.addItem(row)
 log.info("ROWS ${row}")
}``` so it seems did the trick! Am I correct assuming that there is no chance to capture these samplers in **View Results in Table** listener?

Comment: Hi @dmitry-t, do you know whether there is a way to change the label for the requests executed inside the parallel controller?  They are always named -0 , -1 etc which makes it impossible to distinguish them in listener output when the parallel controller is used for different sections of a website. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: @NadezhdaSezganova you can add a JSR223 PostProcessor with the following code: `prev.getSubResults().each(result -> {
 result.setSampleLabel(result.getURL().toString()) // override the default label with the URL
})`